# Why am I getting "401 unauthorized" sometimes in gcloud API on GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-apiserver, kubernetes-python-client

I have a google kubernetes cluster running and I am trying to manually scale some pods with the python-client kubernetes SDK. I use the following  command on my terminal to get my google account credentials:

```
gcloud auth login
```

Next, I connect to my cluster using the default command to get locally my kube-config:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials ${clusterName} --zone ${zoneName}--${projectName}
```

Using the python SDK I load my configuration:

```
from kubernetes import client, config
import kubernetes.client

config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
api = client.CustomObjectsApi()
k8s_apps_v1 = client.AppsV1Api()
```

With this code I have my cluster info and I can  scale my pods as needed. This works for around 30-45 mins and after that when I try to make API requests to scale the pods in my cluster I get a response with the following error:

```
kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '697f82b7-4db9-46c3-b873-cef49a45bb19', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Tue, 31 May 2022 01:20:53 GMT', 'Content-Length': '129'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}
```

Why do I get anauthorized and can't make API calls anymore, and how can I fix this ?

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the token before to call the API? This [doc](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python-base/blob/474e9fb32293fa05098e920967bb0e0645182d5b/config/kube_config.py#L625) could help you  to check if the token expired, the function `load_gcp_token` refreshes the GCP token only if it expires.

Comment: Yep that was the problem, the token was expiring and I wasn't refreshing it thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve it, you should refresh the token before calling the API. This [doc](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python-base/blob/474e9fb32293fa05098e920967bb0e0645182d5b/config/kube_config.py#L625) is useful to check if the token expired, the function `load_gcp_token` refreshes the GCP token only if it expires.